# Trouble with js script for mp3 functionality

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, audio, ejs

Im new to this site and am need of help with my project. 
Keep in mind that I am not the most experienced programmer, so forgive me if my code seems to be a bit sloppy.

I am developing a music production related app using express.js.
In the show page, I am creating a mini mp3 player for each song in an array, which will soon be a database.

In the main app, I am passing the array of song urls into a .ejs file that displays the audio players.
"songs" is the array of mp3 urls.

```
    app.get("/homepage", function(req, res){
    //rendering the homepage ejs
    res.render("show.ejs", {songs:songs});
    });
```

In the .ejs file, I am creating an mp3 player for each song in the array...

```
    <% include partials/header %>

    <div class="container" id="mainBody">
    <div class="row text-center" style="display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap;">
    <% songs.forEach(function(song){%>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
             ....audio player display html....
```

I wrote the functionality for each mp3 player in js, under each object in this page. I know this may not seem like the most ideal thing, but for now Im just tryna make this work.

```
    ...after html for object...
    ...javascript for functionality....
    <% if(song) { %>
                        <script type="text/javascript">

                            window.onload = initAudioPlayer;
                            function initAudioPlayer(){
                                var track = new Audio();
                                track.src="<%=song%>";

                                //play/pause function
                                document.getElementById("switchId").addEventListener("click", function(){
                                    if(track.paused){
                                        track.play();
                                        $('#switchId .fa').toggleClass('fa fa-play fa fa-pause');
                                    }else{
                                        track.pause();
                                        $('#switchId .fa').toggleClass('fa fa-pause fa fa-play');
                                    }
                                });


                            }
                        </script>
                    <% } %>
```

When I run this code, it displays the right amount of audio players (2 songs = 2 mini mp3 players). However, when the functionality works only on the first mp3 player. When I try to click play on the others, it doesnt work. Plus, the mp3 player that works plays the last audio in the array. Im trying everything, and Im not getting very far. Can someone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems that I can spot:

### Why does only the first player work?

This is probably browser-dependent, but:

```
document.getElementById("switchId")
```

IDs are supposed to be unique; if you have more than one element named `switchId` it's likely your browser is only picking the first one.

### Why does that player play the *last* song?

The problem is:

```
window.onload = initAudioPlayer;
```

That's running once for every MP3 player on your page, but the `onload` function is only being *called* later when the window is fully loaded.  As such, it only runs the last one you assigned (since that one overwrote all the previous ones).

Comment: thanks for the input. youre right about the first point, i didnt notice that i have assigned multiple ids. As for the second point, im going to do some research on how to work around this bc i have no idea of an approach. I appreciate your help tho